Custom PHP contact form issue
I'm building a WP website with a custom contact form in PHP, HTML and Javascript.
The issue is when the user click the submit button to send the form, it redirects to a 404 page.
The PHP function:
add_shortcode( 'contact-form', 'display_contact_form' );

function display_contact_form() {

    $validation_messages = [];
    $success_message = '';

    if ( isset( $_POST['contact_form'] ) ) {

        //Sanitize the data
        $name = isset( $_POST['name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['name'] ) : '';
        $surname = isset( $_POST['surname'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['surname'] ) : '';
        $email     = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email'] ) : '';
        $message   = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['message'] ) : '';

        //Validate the data
        if ( strlen( $name ) === 0 ) {
            $validation_messages[] = esc_html__( 'Por favor, introduzca un nombre.', 'mysite' );
        }

        if ( strlen( $surname ) === 0 ) {
            $validation_messages[] = esc_html__( 'Por favor, introduzca un apellido.', 'mysite' );
        }

        if ( strlen( $email ) === 0 or
             ! is_email( $email ) ) {
            $validation_messages[] = esc_html__( 'Por favor, introduzca un correo electrónico válido.', 'mysite' );
        }

        if ( strlen( $message ) === 0 ) {
            $validation_messages[] = esc_html__( 'Por favor, introduzca un mensaje.', 'mysite' );
        }

        //Send an email to the WordPress administrator if there are no validation errors
        if ( empty( $validation_messages ) ) {

            $mail    = get_option( 'admin_email' );
            $subject = 'Nuevo mensaje de ' . $surname;
            $message = $message . ' - El email del cliente es: ' . $mail;

            wp_mail( $mail, $subject, $message );

            $success_message = esc_html__( 'Su mensaje ha sido enviado con éxito.', 'mysite' );

        }

    }

    //Display the validation errors
    if ( ! empty( $validation_messages ) ) {
        foreach ( $validation_messages as $validation_message ) {
            echo '<div class="c-form__validation-message">' . esc_html( $validation_message ) . '</div>';
        }
    }

    //Display the success message
    if ( strlen( $success_message ) > 0 ) {
        echo '<div class="c-form__success-message">' . esc_html( $success_message ) . '</div>';
    }

    ?>

    <div id="validation-messages-container" class="c-form__validation"></div>

    <form id="contact-form" class="c-form__form" action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="contact_form">

        <div class="c-form__section">
            <label for="name" class="c-form__label"><?php echo esc_html( 'Nombre', 'mysite' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="c-form__input" name="name" placeholder="<?php echo esc_html( 'Nombre', 'mysite' ); ?>">
        </div>

        <div class="c-form__section">
            <label for="surname" class="c-form__label"><?php echo esc_html( 'Apellidos', 'mysite' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="surname" class="c-form__input" name="surname" placeholder="<?php echo esc_html( 'Apellidos', 'mysite' ); ?>">
        </div>

        <div class="c-form__section">
            <label for="email" class="c-form__label"><?php echo esc_html( 'Email', 'mysite' ); ?></label>
            <input type="email" id="email" class="c-form__input" name="email" placeholder="<?php echo esc_html( 'Email', 'mysite' ); ?>">
        </div>

        <div class="c-form__section">
            <label for="message" class="c-form__label"><?php echo esc_html( 'Mensaje', 'mysite' ); ?></label>
            <textarea id="message" class="c-form__textarea" name="message" placeholder="<?php echo esc_html( 'Mensaje', 'mysite' ); ?>"></textarea>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" id="contact-form-submit" class="c-form__submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( 'Enviar', 'mysite' ); ?>">

    </form>

    <?php
}

The JS:
const contactFormSubmit = document.getElementById('contact-form-submit');
contactFormSubmit.addEventListener('click', validateForm);

function validateForm(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  // Name
  const name = document.getElementById('name') !== null ?
      document.getElementById('name').value :
      '';

  // Surname
  const surname = document.getElementById('surname') !== null ?
      document.getElementById('surname').value :
      '';

  // Email
  const email = document.getElementById('email') !== null ?
      document.getElementById('email').value :
      '';

  // Message
  const message = document.getElementById('message') !== null ?
      document.getElementById('message').value :
      '';

  const validationMessages = [];
  if (name.length === 0) {
    validationMessages.push('Por favor, introduzca un nombre.');
  }
  
  if (surname.length === 0) {
    validationMessages.push('Por favor, introduzca un apellido.');
  }

  if (email.length === 0 || !emailIsValid(email)) {
    validationMessages.push('Por favor, introduzca un email valido.');
  }

  if (message.length === 0) {
    validationMessages.push('Por favor, introduzca un mensaje.');
  }

  if (validationMessages.length === 0) {

    //Submit the form
    document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();

  } else {

    //Delete all the existing validation messages from the DOM
    const parent = document.getElementById('validation-messages-container');
    while (parent.firstChild) {
      parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
    }

    //Add the new validation messages to the DOM
    validationMessages.forEach(function(validationMessage, index) {

      //add message to the DOM
      const divElement = document.createElement('div');
      divElement.classList.add('validation-message');
      const node = document.createTextNode(validationMessage);
      divElement.appendChild(node);

      const element = document.getElementById('validation-messages-container');
      element.appendChild(divElement);

    });

  }

}

Thank you.

Just found the issue. The error came from the PHP variable $name. This variable seems to be reserved by Wordpress and can't be used.

Glad you solved it, feel free to post that as an answer if you want. However AFAICS WordPress doesn't have a $name global, nor can I see anything else that would break if you used $name.
